# HTTP request failing in Installshield custom action

Tags: c#, installshield, custom-action

I am writing a custom action to hit an https endpoint to check a license key. The custom action code works fine if i run it outside of installshield in a console application, so i know the code works fine.

****Running Installshield 2023 Premier**

When i pull this into either a managed OR unmanaged installshield custom action, it fails. The error its throwing is:

```
.....
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
.....
```

I saw a similar exception when i had the CA .Net version set lower than 4.6.1. When i bumped that up then the exception stopped happening in the console testing that i was doing. So it seems that installshield is sandboxing the custom action somehow?!?

Comment: Best practice with making a secure connection is to use Net 4.7.1 or newer and use the default option to allow OS to perform TLS (SSL is obsolete).  TLS 1.2 or 1.3 are only valid versions.  TLS will also fail with older OS especially using TLS 1.3 with a IIS system.  The error you are getting is a timeout that connection did not complete.  It could be TLS or lots of other reasons connection do not complete. Often TLS fails if the certificate is not properly loaded on both client and server. Code may be working when run As Admin and not working inside installshield because you are not an admin.

Comment: What do you mean by use default option to allow OS to perform TLS? Also yea the installer is running with admin privilages.

Comment: TLS is performed before the HTTP request is sent to establish a encrypted connection between client and server. TLS before 4.7.1 was done inside the Net library. Now it is performed by the OS.